# Parent version defined in parent

Tags: java, maven

I have done the following structure of poms:

foo/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>art-foo</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>${global.project.version}</version>

<properties>
    <global.project.version>1.0.0.0</global.project.version>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>bar</module>
</modules>
```

foo/bar/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
<artifactId>art-bar</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>art-foo</artifactId>
    <version>${global.project.version}</version>
</parent>
```

The problem is that when I do the `mvn clean install` it makes the build successfully, and I don't understand why it works and how the son is able to get the parent version property defined in the parent.

Additionally, I've tried editing the parent pom to the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>art-foo</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0.0.0</version>

<properties>
    <global.project.version>1.0.0.0</global.project.version>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>bar</module>
</modules>
```

and this time I get an error when compiling, which is normal as the son cannot see the parent property.

The question is, why the first build finishes successfully and the second doesn't?

Thanks.